# Print k next Permutations of n digit numbers in lexicographical order

Tags: arrays, algorithm, permutation

I wanted to generate next k permutations from given set of n digits in lexicographical order.

initial array and k is given.
like let starting array be 1 2 4 3
then next 3 permutations would be
1 3 2 4:
1 3 4 2:
1 4 3 2:

i tried

```
static void permute(int arr[], int low, int high) {
    if (low == high) {
        printArray(arr);
        return;
    }
    for (int i=low; i<high; i++) {
        swap(arr, i, low);
        permute(arr, low+1, high);
        swap(arr, low, i);
    }
}

static void swap(int arr[], int i, int j) {
    int t = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = t;
}
```

but this is not giving the permutations in lexicographical order. and also i am not able to restrict upto next k permutations.

Comment: https://www.nayuki.io/page/next-lexicographical-permutation-algorithm

Answer (score 0):

I've created a solution in JAVA. I had to use BigInteger because the number of permutations could be astronomical as we increase the length of the array. (For short arrays you can change it to long.)

The complexity is only O(n*length), so using these complex objects is not a problem as long as you don't want to calculate millions of permutations.

It also has 2 additional useful methods:

```
BigInteger calculatePermutationNumber(Integer[] arr)
```

It calculates an array's position in the lexicographical order of this array's permutations.

```
Integer[] createNthPermutation(Integer[] arr, BigInteger n)
```

It creates the Nth permutation of the given (sorted) array. So you can use it to calculate ANY permutation, not only the next or the previous ones.

The algorithm itself is in the following method:

```
Integer[][] createNextXPermutation(Integer[] arr, int x)
```

None of the above methods checks the validity of the input parameters. Although it has an interesting side effect: If you call the function with arguments where there are not enough permutations left in the lexicographical order then it will roll over and continue listing the permutations from the beginning. Could be useful in certain cases. :)

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author Selindek
 */
public class Permutation {

    public static void main(String... args) {

        Integer[] array = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 4, 3 };

        int n = 3;
        Integer[][] result = createNextXPermutation(array, n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.asList(result[i]));
        }
    }

    public static Integer[][] createNextXPermutation(Integer[] arr, int x) {
        Integer[][] ret = new Integer[x][];

        BigInteger n = calculatePermutationNumber(arr);
        Integer digits[] = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length);
        Arrays.sort(digits);
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            ret[i] = createNthPermutation(digits, n.add(BigInteger.valueOf(i + 1)));
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public static BigInteger calculatePermutationNumber(Integer[] arr) {
        int length = arr.length;
        Integer digits[] = Arrays.copyOf(arr, length);
        Arrays.sort(digits);
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(digits));
        BigInteger n = BigInteger.ZERO;
        for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
            int index = list.indexOf(arr[i]);
            list.remove(index);
            n = n.add(BigInteger.valueOf(index));
            n = n.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(length - 1 - i));
        }
        return n;
    }

    public static Integer[] createNthPermutation(Integer[] arr, BigInteger n) {
        int length = arr.length;
        Integer[] ret = new Integer[length];
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr));
        int[] pos = new int[length];

        for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
            BigInteger[] div = n.divideAndRemainder(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
            n = div[0];
            pos[length - i] = div[1].intValue();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            ret[i] = list.remove(pos[i]);
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```